# How to get the value inside the onNext to access it outside in my code

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

i am using mvvm pattern in my app here my example of code :

```
    let userVM = UserViewModel()

    userVM.getUser()
        .subscribeOn(SerialDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .background))
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { user in
            self.user = user
        }, onError: { error in
            
        }, onCompleted: {
            
        }, onDisposed: {
            
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

i want to access the user emitted onNext outside the onSubscribe function any help with that ?

Comment: Why do you want that? What is the problem you are trying to solve, because there is probably a better way.

Comment: > In production code, it is rarely advised to 'break the monad', especially moving from an observable sequence to blocking methods. Switching between asynchronous and synchronous paradigms should be done with caution, as this is a common root cause for concurrency problems such as deadlock and scalability issues.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use any API calls on View.
Make output subscriber on your ViewModel and drive it to your view.

***Example ViewModel:***

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxDataSources

extension ModelListViewModel {
    enum Sections: SectionModelType {
        typealias Item = ModelDTO
        
        case model(models: [Item])
        
        var items: [Item]  {
            switch self {
            case .model(let models):
                return models
            }
        }
        
        init(original: Sections, items: [Item]) {
            self = original
        }
    }
}

class ModelListViewModel {
    //inputs
    let didLoad = PublishSubject<Void>()
    let modelSelected = PublishSubject<ModelDTO>()
    //outputs
    let sections: Driver<[Sections]>
    
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private static var data: [ModelDTO] = {
        var array = [ModelDTO]()
        guard let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "seat_medium_quality_m_center", withExtension: "usdz") else {
            return []
        }
        let firstModel = ModelDTO(url: urlPath, modelName: "Seat 1")
        let secondModel = ModelDTO(url: urlPath, modelName: "Seat 2")
        let thirdModel = ModelDTO(url: urlPath, modelName: "Seat 3")
        return [firstModel, secondModel, thirdModel]
    }()
    init(context: ARRouter.ModelListContext) {
        //TODO: Make sections due to responce from BackEnd
        sections = didLoad
            .mapTo([Sections.model(models: ModelListViewModel.data)])
            .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .empty())
        
        modelSelected.map { $0.url }
            .bind(to: context.modelSelectedIn)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }    
 }
```

***Example of ViewController:***

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import RxDataSources

class ModelListViewController: BaseViewController {
    private struct Cells {
        static let modelListCell = ReusableCell<ModelListCell>(nibName: "ModelListCell")
    }
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.register(Cells.modelListCell)
            
            viewModel.sections
                .drive(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
            
            tableView.rx
                .modelSelected(ModelDTO.self)
                .bind(to: viewModel.modelSelected)
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
    }
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let viewModel: ModelListViewModel
    private let dataSource: RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<ModelListViewModel.Sections>
    
    init(viewModel: ModelListViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.dataSource = .init(configureCell: { (_, tableView, indexPath, item) -> UITableViewCell in
            let cell = tableView.dequeue(Cells.modelListCell, for: indexPath)
            cell.setup(with: item)
            return cell
        })
        super.init(nibName: "ModelListViewController", bundle: nil)
        
        rx.viewDidLoad
            .bind(to: viewModel.didLoad)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```